# Multivariate multiple linear regression with many dependent variables

Tags: r

How does one run multivariate linear regressions if there are a lot of dependent variables, say in my case 222 to be exact? I want to regress certain values I have for 222 different companies with few regressors.

I know i can do e.g.

```
y <- cbind(y1, y2, y3... yn)
fit <- lm(y ~ X1 + X2 + ... Xn)
```

But there has to be a clever way to cbind my columns other than writing by hand `cbind(y1, y2, y3, ...y222)` 
- right?

I have tried `cbind(vol[, 2:223])` but placing that in y and given to lm() function only results in `Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ RMF + SMB + HML, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'y'`

Not very experienced with R so I appreciate all the help I can get for my thesis! Please bear with me.

Comment: linear regression with 222 variables is not a good idea. Consider ridge regression, lasso, or principal component regression. As for the binding of data I think we would need a reproducible example to provide solutions to the `model.matrix` problem.

Comment: From what I understand, you already have all the predictors in variable vol which is either a matrix or dataframe. You can just do `vol = vol[-1,]; lm(vol~X)`. However this is a lot of dimensions for y to use directly. I'd suggest doing dimension reduction methods (for ex. PCA) to get y to a smaller dimension first :)

Answer (score 1):

Below we use the built-in `anscombe` data frame as an example.

**1)** The key part is to use a matrix, not a data frame, for the left hand side of the formula.  In the example below we define a matrix `y` of the dependent variables and then use that with `lm`:

```
y <- as.matrix(anscombe[5:8])
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, anscombe)
```

**1a)** or if there are many independent variables too:

```
lm(y ~ ., anscombe[1:4])
```

**2)** One could alternately use `lm.fit`.  Note that it does not automatically add an intercept so we add one:

```
m <- as.matrix(anscombe)
lm.fit(cbind(Intercept = 1, m[, 1:4]), m[, 5:8])
```

`lm.fit` returns a list rather than an `lm` object but some methods such as `coef` and `resid` (but not `summary`) work with it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, all 222 vectors are of same length and your global environment has no other object except these 222 vectors, you can try:

**Method 1:**

```
library(purrr)

# get all 223 vectors in a list
vec_list <- as.list(.GlobalEnv))

# cbind the list elements
df <- map_df(vec_list, cbind)
```

Method 2:

```
# this lists all the objects in your current environment
vec_list= ls()

# get data
df <- cbind(vec_list)
```